# ¿Como puedo pasar un archivo con extension txt a excel? (Visual Basic)

Tags: vba

Necesito un codigo que me permita seleccionar desde un path un archivo txt específico y que lo pase a una hoja de excel seleccionada.

[image: Este es el codigo que utilizaba hasta el momento]

El problema surge con que quiero un archivo txt en especifico y ese codigo lo realice  para que agarre varios archivos de una misma ruta y los pase (cambiaba la extension de el excel habilitado para macros .xslm a .txt)

Comment: Por favor, pon tu código como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aqui te dejo un [mcve]